# Entering data with Input[] in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How can i  make in this code the text in Dialog Box of the Input command to be like this "Enter the 1 element","Enter the 2 element"....

```
For[k = 1, k ≤ n, k++,
  br = Input["Enter the ",i,"element"];
  AppendTo[x, br];
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your variables match. :-)

You can use `Row` to build up the text.

```
x = {};
n = 3;
For[k = 1, k <= n, k++,
 br = Input[Row[{"Enter the ", k, " element"}]];
 AppendTo[x, br];
 ]
```

(You could also use `StringJoin["Enter the ", ToString[k], " element"]`, but I like `Row` better.)

Answer (score 1):

According to the **Input[ ]** help:

```
The prompt given can be text, graphics or any expression.
```

So, anything will fit in the input prompt!

Just as an example (note the explicit loop is not needed):

```
x = Input[
    Panel[Grid@{{Row[{"Enter the element number ", #}]}, 
                     {PolyhedronData["Platonic", {"Image"}][[Mod[#, 5] + 1]]}}]
         ] & /@ Range[1, 5]
```

Will show things like:

[image]