# keyboard functions in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to find out what keyboard functionalities Mathematica has. Would appreciate anyone to give some help. Specifically, I want to:

1) How to implement something like "press any key to continue..." behavior

2) How to accept user input?

Many thanks.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427784/entering-data-with-input-in-mathematica/5427927#5427927) answer is relevant. Probably the code presented there is similar to what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you'll want to look at [`Input`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Input.html) and [`ChoiceDialog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ChoiceDialog.html) for something simple.

If you want to build your own interface, you can use the dynamic interactivity components with [`CreateDialog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CreateDialog.html) to construct a custom notebook dialog window to accept and return whatever kind of input you'd like.

You might find the [Introduction to Control Objects](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/IntroductionToControlObjects.html) and [Generalized Input](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/GeneralizedInput.html) tutorials useful as well.