# How to show plots inside a loop in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am wondering if you have good ways to show plots inside a loop in mma. Usually, the output of `Plot` function is not shown, for example in the following code:

`For[i = 1, i <= 10, i++, Plot[Sin[i*x], {x, -Pi, Pi}]]`

Thanks for your help.

**Edit**

In connection to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573231/keyboard-functions-in-mathematica), I already have the For loop, for example, like this `For[i = 1, i <= 10, i++, Plot[Sin[i*x], {x, -Pi, Pi}]]`. Given this fact, I want to have something like "press any key to continue..." inside the For loop, then refresh the plot every time I press any random key. Could anybody give a complete working code?

Comment: Does it have to be a keypress, and only moving forward? There's always [Manipulate](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Manipulate.html).

Comment: @Jefromi: Yes, ideally I want to have key press.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just use `Print`:

```
For[i = 1, i <= 10, i++, Plot[Sin[i*x], {x, -Pi, Pi}] // Print]
```

or `Monitor`:

```
Monitor[For[i = 1, i <= 10, i++, p = Plot[Sin[i*x], {x, -Pi, Pi}]; 
  Pause[0.5]], p]
```

(Pause is used here to give some time to view the plot; the loop is pretty fast here. Remove if necessary)

**EDIT**
On request a version that is controlled by *mouse* clicks on the graph (key presses need the graph to have focus so you need to click anyway)

```
Monitor[For[i = 1, i <= 10, , p = Plot[Sin[i*x], {x, -Pi, Pi}]], 
EventHandler[p, {"MouseDown" :> i++}]]
```

This is a pretty stupid way to do this. The loop redraws the plot continuously. So, a slightly (but still ugly) version might be:

```
s = True;
Monitor[
 For[i = 1, i <= 10, ,
  If[s,
   (* Put main loop body here*) 
   p = Plot[Sin[i*x], {x, -Pi, Pi}] 
   (* end of main body *) ;
   s = False (* prevents continuous re-evaluating main body *)
   ]
  ]
 , EventHandler[p, {"MouseDown" :> (i++; s = True)}]
 ]
```

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries: thank you. This does plot, but it generates a lot of plots. Ideally I want the plot to refresh after I press any key. Do you know how to achieve this effect?

Comment: @Qiang You changed your question after I gave this answer. Do you still want it inside a For loop? In the meantime Michael already provide an answer without it.

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries: Yes, I still want it inside a For loop.

Comment: @Sjoerd: It's tricky to get this working with a keyboard event, because the notebook focus moves off the plot. Trying to combine it with a NotebookMove[] runs into problems with not actually displaying the Plot. The only way I could work around it was with explicit (cell) print and cell delete commands...

Comment: @Simon: would you please post the working code here? The one given by Sjoerd C. de Vries did not work on my side. My Mma version is 7.0; I initially thought it was because I am using an old version. THanks.

Comment: @QiangLi: Not right now (I deleted my notebook) -- got to head off for the rest of the day. Think about the sequence of events: 1) Print the plot; 2) Move selection onto plot; 3) on key press delete cell and print new one. Look up `SelectionMove` and `NotebookDelete` in the documentation center and modify the `EventHandler` code of Sjoerd.

Comment: The nice thing about using `Dynamic` is that it doesn't update anything until the tracked variables change, avoiding the need for a hack to prevent continuous re-evaluation as above.

Comment: @Simon you can also use `PrintTemporary` which acts like `Print` but returns a `NotebookInterfaceObject` you can pass to `NotebookDelete` in the same evaluation, removing the cell. Avoids the need to use `SelectionMove`.

Comment: @Michael: I was just about to give you +100 for that suggestion, then I remembered that the `SelectionMove` is so that the Graphics/Monitored object is selected and the EventHandler can pick up a keyboard input....

Comment: Ah, yes I forgot about the keyboard focus issue. I'll give this whole question some more thought...

Answer (score 15):

Just return a list of the plots, instead of using a `For` loop:

```
Table[Plot[Sin[i*x], {x, -Pi, Pi}], {i, 1, 10}]
```

[image]

If you want them all concatenated as one plot, `Show[listOfPlots]` is one way to do that:

```
Show[Table[Plot[Sin[i*x], {x, -Pi, Pi}], {i, 1, 10}]]
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

Here's one simple way using `Dynamic` and `EventHandler`:

```
DynamicModule[{i = 1},
 EventHandler[Dynamic[Plot[Sin[i*x], {x, -Pi, Pi}]],
  {"KeyDown" :> i++}
  ]
```

And here's a slightly more fancy interface made with `Animate`:

```
Animate[Plot[Sin[i*x], {x, -Pi, Pi}], {i, 1, 10, 1}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have editted my post, hopefully this time it is more clear.

Comment: I added an example in my edit. Don't be afraid to use the built-in tools for this sort of thing either, like `Animate` and `Manipulate`.

Answer (score 6):

If you really want to have the user press a key between Plots, the simplest way might be

```
For[i = 1, i <= 10, i++, 
    If[!ChoiceDialog[Plot[Sin[i*x], {x, -Pi, Pi}], 
         WindowTitle -> "Plot #" <> ToString[i] 
                                 <> ":  Press OK or Enter to continue"],
    Abort[]]]
```

[image]

Comment: I keep pressing the OK button and nothing happens. BTW the cancel button doesn't work either. Is it a bug on your program, or just a Mozilla compatibility issue?

Comment: @belisarius: You had me going for a second...  :P

Comment: Simon, congratulations on breaking 3K rep.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Thanks! You're catching up fast though... you're in the top 2% this month.